Dotted Chess Board Style
I found this old chessboard style in a magazine

I really like the design, the black fields are dotted and around the chessboard there are the labels on all sides and around that there is the border. Is it possible to implement this in LaTeX? I did not find anything on that matter.
Here is a classic chessboard:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{geometry}
 

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\chessboard[ setfen=1r3b1k/2RnqB2/5n2/6Q1/4p3/1P5P/3N1PP1/6K1 w - - 0 1, label=true, showmover=false]
\end{center} 

\end{document}

With label=true I can get the labels on all four sides.

welcome! what have you tried? can you implement a non-dotted chessboard with, say, the chessboard package?

Let's replace "magazine" by "newspaper". Most likely the black fields where gray, to let a black figure be visible when standing on a black field. To print gray with just black color in the press, gray areas, like in photos, were rasterized. This process created the dots. // In Latex you'd need to mimick this process. One way, out of many alternatives, would be to put dot-patterns inside the to-be-black fields, e.g. via Tikz. An other is image processing.  // In IT-terms you'd keep the chess core (recorded moves etc.) and replace its visual presentation.

This package seems to travel the replacing route: https://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard . It uses stripes or colors as fill, and may be open to using dots.

Well a font with such a field mask would be better, but you can do it with patterns:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LSBC5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter
\cbDefinePgfFieldStyle{dots}{%
    \pgfsetfillpattern{crosshatch dots}{gray}%or some other color
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners%
      {\pgfpointadd%
       {\pgfpoint{-\board@pgf@padding}{\board@pgf@padding}}%
       {\pgfpointxy{-0.5}{0.5}}}%
      {\pgfpointadd%
       {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
       {\pgfpointadd%
        {\pgfpoint{\board@pgf@padding}{-\board@pgf@padding}}%
        {\pgfpointxy{0.5}{-0.5}}}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke,fill}}%
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard
[boardfontencoding=LSBC5,
 boardfontsize=20pt,
 backstyle=dots,
 trimtocolor=black,backboard]
\end{document}



Great! Few improvements: add \usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}. Then replace \pgfsetfillpattern{crosshatch dots}{gray} by \pgfsetfillpattern{Dots[radius=0.65pt,angle=45,distance={2.65pt/sqrt(2)}]}{gray}. And replace \chessboard[boardfontencoding=LSBC5,boardfontsize=20pt,backstyle=dots,trimtocolor=black,backboard] by \fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\chessboard[boardfontencoding=LSBC5,boardfontsize=20pt,backstyle=dots,trimtocolor=black,backboard,label=true,showmover=false,labeltoplift=0.4\baselineskip,marginwidth=5mm]}. So, dots more dense, frame around the chessboard and little square at right gone.

With MPchess, there is now a Dotted theme, and you can also define the backboard with the User theme :
% lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
input mpchess;

beginfig(0);
set_color_theme("Dotted");
init_backboard;
draw backboard;
init_chessboard;
draw chessboard;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin{mplibcode}
input mpchess;

def buildUserSquare(expr _SquareUnit)=
    _blackSquarePic:=image(
        fill (unitsquare scaled _SquareUnit) withcolor white;
        save N;
        N:= 11;
        for i:=0 upto N+1:
            for j:=0 upto N+1:
                fill ((fullcircle scaled 0.7) shifted (1/N*i*_SquareUnit if odd(j): +1/(2*N)*_SquareUnit fi,1/N*j*_SquareUnit))
                ;
            endfor;
        endfor;
        draw (unitsquare  scaled _SquareUnit);
        clip currentpicture to (unitsquare  scaled _SquareUnit);
    );
    _whiteSquarePic:=image(
        fill unitsquare scaled _SquareUnit withcolor white;
        draw (unitsquare  scaled _SquareUnit);
        clip currentpicture to (unitsquare  scaled _SquareUnit);
    );
enddef;

beginfig(1);
set_color_theme("User");
init_backboard;
draw backboard;
init_chessboard;
draw chessboard;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}


